# check size of UIImageView is smaller than original when pinching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

so I've loaded up an UIImageView and had a a PinchGestureRecognizer in it, the question now is how do I detect if the UIImageView size is smaller than the original size (before it was pinched)? The way I do it now is this:

```
- (IBAction)resizeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView * imgView = (UIImageView *)[fullSizeImageView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale);

    NSLog(@"SCALE IS %f WITH STATE %d", sender.scale, sender.state);
    if (imgView.frame.size.width < oriWidth && imgView.frame.size.height < oriHeight) {
       //then it's size is smaller than original
    }
}
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just scaling the UIImageView based on the scale of the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, wouldn't a scale value < 1.0 mean that the UIImageView is smaller than it originally was?

Comment: but that would also mean that if I scale to 2x then I stopped at 1.5, that will still detect the image is smaller.. whilst it's not

Comment: If you are only scaling the image view and never rotating it, then `sender.view.transform.a` and `sender.view.transform.d` (i.e. the two diagonal elements of the transformation matrix) should both be equal to the cumulative scale factor that has been applied to the view. So try checking if one of those values is < 1.0. I'm pretty sure it should work even if you have done multiple pinches.